# Unable to install the openssh-server on ubuntu. sizemismatch error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openssh

I am trying to install openssh-server on my Ubuntu-14.04.1. At a point it is throwing error like this.

```
>sudo apt-get update

>sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

...

The following NEW packages will be installed:

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-sftp-server_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb  **Size mismatch**

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**if try with the --fix-missing , also not working**

```
>sudo apt-get install openssh-server --fix-missing

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

...

Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-sftp-server_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb  **Size mismatch**

E: Aborting install.
```

Please , can any one suggest me to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're using an invalid mirror. Just googling a bit you will easily find how to change your current mirror to a different one. Here's an answer from another Stack Exchange community:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/ubuntu-repository-change